# How to compute $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{n(n+2)}{3^n}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

so I am having problems finding the value of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{n(n+2)}{3^n}}$. WolframAlpha says it should be $=3$, but what's the reasoning behind it? Can I just look at $1/3^n$ since the series is absolutetly convergent and we can disregard some terms...

Comment: Consider $\sum n(n+2)x^n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following may be useful.

Let $F(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$, which equals $\displaystyle {1\over1-x}$ if $|x|<1$. Then also for $|x|<1$, $$F'(x)=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\cdots$$
$${F'(x)-1\over x}=2+3x+4x^2+5x^3\cdots$$
$${d\over dx}{F'(x)-1\over x}=(1\cdot3)+(2\cdot4)x+(3\cdot5)x^2+\cdots$$
$$x{d\over dx}{F'(x)-1\over x}=(1\cdot3)x+(2\cdot4)x^2+(3\cdot5)x^3+\cdots$$

If you evaluate both sides of the final equation at $x={1\over3}$, you will find your answer.

Answer (score 4):

[Telescopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) approach. Note that
$$\frac{n(n+2)}{3^n}=a_n-a_{n+1}$$
where
$$a_n=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2\cdot 3^{n-1}}.$$
Hence
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}{\frac{n(n+2)}{3^n}}=(a_0-a_1)+(a_1-a_2)+\dots+(a_{N-1}-a_N)=a_0-a_{N}=3-a_N$$
and it follows that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{n(n+2)}{3^n}}=3-\lim_{N\to \infty}a_N=3-0=3.$$

Comment: How do you find $a_n$?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic I made a guess: $a_n$ has a "similar" form i.e. a quadratic polynomial over $3^n$. Then I found the coefficients so that $\frac{n(n+2)}{3^n}=a_n-a_{n+1}$ holds.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$\dfrac{n(n+2)}{3^n}=f(n+1)-f(n)$$ to form a https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

where $f(m)3^m=a_0+a_1m+a_2m^2+a_3m^3+\cdots$

$3n(n+2)=a_0+a_1(n+1)+a_2(n+1)^2+\cdots$

$-3(a_0+a_1n+a_2n^2+\cdots)$

Comparing the coefficients of $n^2,$ $$3=a_2-3a_2\iff a_2=?$$

Compare the coefficients of $n,$ $$6=2a_2+a_1-3a_1\implies a_1=?$$

Compare the constant, $$0=a_0+a_1+a_2-3(a_0+a_1+a_2)\implies a_0=?$$

Of course, we need to establish $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=0$$

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic,  This is how we can find $f(m)$ in generic way